# prisma findUnique with where throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prisma

I am trying to create Singup API in ExpressJS and Prisma.

I am checking whether given email exists in my database or not. When I pass  the email and password, it throws  `Unknown arg email in where.email for type SignupWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean id? Available args:` error.

I tried using select: { email: true, password: true } but its not working. Code is working only if I pass id number instead of email. Any ideas what is wrong here??

```js
router.post(`/signup`, async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

  const checkEmail = await prisma.signup.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: email
    }
  });

  if (checkEmail) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "Pick different one"
    });
  }
  const userSignUp = await prisma.signup.create({
    data: {
      email,
      password: hashPassword
    }
  });

  return res.json(userSignUp);
});

// DB Schema
model Signup {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  email    String
  password String
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because the `email` field in your Prisma `Signup` model is not *unique*. The `where` option in a `findUnique` query only accepts *unique* fields of a model. This is done to ensure that only *one record* can be specified by a `findUnique` query. If you're interested to know more, the [Prisma Client API reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference/#findunique) explains this behavior in some depth.

To solve the error, make the `email` field unique inside your Prisma Schema file. The updated `Signup` model should look like this:

```
model Signup {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email    String   @unique      
  password String 
}
```